# Js:Calling a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I use Maplace.js, A Google Maps Javascript plugin for jQuery.
In a plugin has a function that will display the marker on the map.

```
//triggers to show a location in map
    Maplace.prototype.ViewOnMap = function (index) {
        //view all
        if (index === this.view_all_key) {
            this.o.beforeViewAll();
            this.current_index = index;
            if (this.o.locations.length > 0 && this.o.generate_controls && this.current_control && this.current_control.activateCurrent) {
                this.current_control.activateCurrent.apply(this, [index]);
            }
            this.oMap.fitBounds(this.oBounds);
            this.CloseInfoWindow();
            this.o.afterViewAll();

        //specific location
        } else {
            index = parseInt(index, 10);
            if (typeof (index - 0) === 'number' && index > 0 && index <= this.ln) {
                try {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(this.markers[index - 1], 'click');
                } catch (err) {
                    this.debug('ViewOnMap::trigger', err.stack);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
```

I try to call this method but to no avail:

```
<a href="javascript:Maplace.prototype.ViewOnMap(2)">Link</a>
```

how can I call from a link with key?

Answer (score 0):

Since `ViewOnMap` is defined on `Maplace` prototype, it means that this is an instance method. So you should call it on Maplace instance object. Something like this:

```
var maplace = new Maplace({ ... });
maplace.Load();
```

and later:

```
<a href="javascript:maplace.ViewOnMap(2)">Link</a>
```

Comment: This option unfortunately I also do not work. Perhaps you have an example of how to do it correctly?

Comment: Can you post your code, how you create Maplace object?

Comment: `<script>

var maplace = new Maplace({
locations: LocsA,
map_div: '#gmap',
    controls_type: 'list',
    controls_on_map: true
  }).Load();

;
</script>`

Comment: I think it should be `var maplace = new Maplace({...}); maplace.Load(); ... maplace.ViewOnMap(2)`. See updated answer.

Comment: If I use `maplace.Load ();` the map is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<a class="openmap" href="#">Link</a>
```

and the js:

```
$('.openmap').on('click', function(e){
e.prevetDefault();
Maplace.prototype.ViewOnMap = function (index) {
        //view all
        if (index === this.view_all_key) {
            this.o.beforeViewAll();
            this.current_index = index;
            if (this.o.locations.length > 0 && this.o.generate_controls && this.current_control && this.current_control.activateCurrent) {
                this.current_control.activateCurrent.apply(this, [index]);
            }
            this.oMap.fitBounds(this.oBounds);
            this.CloseInfoWindow();
            this.o.afterViewAll();

        //specific location
        } else {
            index = parseInt(index, 10);
            if (typeof (index - 0) === 'number' && index > 0 && index <= this.ln) {
                try {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(this.markers[index - 1], 'click');
                } catch (err) {
                    this.debug('ViewOnMap::trigger', err.stack);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried to add js code and the link but for some reason this does not work.  TypeError: e.prevetDefault is not a function
 

e.prevetDefault();

Comment: Hello RQEST, i made a mistake, its called e.preventDefault();

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help, but I found another way to do this, we had to spend a lot of time)).

Answer (score 0):

I decided this question in this way:

```
<a onclick="javascript:maplace.ViewOnMap()" href="#gmap">Link</a>
```

Tried many things, and everything was easy. No need to change anything, or append to the code.
Thank you all.